# How to customize md-select's popup menu in Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I need to define a special class for some `md-select`'s popup menus (not to all). But I have no idea how to do that.

Here is a code sample of typical usage and here is no place where I can define a class for menu container that will appear.

```html
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block defaultInputSelect filterType">
  <md-select ng-model="value.filter_type" md-on-close="viewChanged()">
    <md-option ng-repeat="(key, value) in filterTypes" value="{{value}}">
      {{filterTypesNames[key]}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Actually, I want to change the width of popup menu. By default it is limited by the width of `md-select`.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to do? Maybe then we can point you in the right direction

Comment: @johan, I want to change the width of popup menu. Edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi there please look at the following plunkr, the following selector seems to work fine to affect the whole component

https://plnkr.co/edit/sp7mKuaeztfAgtujARcw?p=preview

```
 <style type="text/css">
    md-input-container,
    md-input-container > * {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  </style>
```

**Edit:** Here you go, this will only affect the select dropdown

https://plnkr.co/edit/sp7mKuaeztfAgtujARcw?p=preview

```
<style type="text/css">
   ._md-select-menu-container
    {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  </style>
```

**Final Edit:** Simply add the md-container-class="myclass" directive to your md-select

https://plnkr.co/edit/sp7mKuaeztfAgtujARcw?p=preview

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .myclass {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
</style>

<md-select md-container-class="myclass" ng-model="selectedItem" md-selected-text="getSelectedText()">
  <md-optgroup label="items">
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in items">Item {{item}}</md-option>
  </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

Comment: This will set width for all md-select menus, but I need to do this only with some of them. That's why I'm looking for solution that uses classes. Also this changes the width of md-select too. I need to set width for popup menu that will be different from md-select width.

Comment: And the last edition is also a different thing from what I want. This will apply CSS rule for all md-select's menus on the page, but I need to apply it only for chosen ones. That's why I started talking about class assignment first.

Comment: ok you can simply add your class as a directive on the desired md-select